# Display horizontal checkboxes in sizers

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to figure a way of displaying check-boxes horizontally.
Perhaps there is a way of using positioning inside sizers.

□ one  □ two  □ three

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,wx.ID_ANY,title='test chkBx')        

        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.vbox= wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.background = wx.Panel(self)

        choices = ['one', 'two', 'three']

        self.chkBx = wx.CheckListBox(self, choices=choices)       
        self.bottomview = wx.TextCtrl(self,
                                     style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_RICH|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)        

        hsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hsizer1.Add(self.chkBx,1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND) 

        hsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hsizer2.Add(self.bottomview,1,flag = wx.EXPAND)        

        self.vbox.Add(hsizer1,proportion = 2,flag = wx.EXPAND)
        self.vbox.Add(hsizer2,proportion = 8,flag = wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.vbox)
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
frame = MainFrame()
app.MainLoop()
```

This will have the appearance of what I want.  But but my list of choices is only 'three'.

```
choices = ['one']
self.chkBx1 = wx.CheckListBox(self, choices=choices)
choices = ['two']
self.chkBx2 = wx.CheckListBox(self, choices=choices)
choices = ['three']
self.chkBx3 = wx.CheckListBox(self, choices=choices)
self.bottomview = wx.TextCtrl(self,
                             style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_RICH|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)        

hsizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
hsizer1.Add(self.chkBx1,1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND)
hsizer1.Add(self.chkBx2,1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND)
hsizer1.Add(self.chkBx3,1,flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.RIGHT|wx.EXPAND)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can use the CheckListBox. However, you could do it manually. You'd have to create the checkboxes yourself though. If you're on wxpython 2.9, you can use the WrapSizer to get multiline support as well, else for single lines, BoxSizer works fine. This isn't a fully working example, but it's actual code from something i wrote, so the basic code should work. self._outsizer was the window sizer, and fieldenum was a bidirectional dictionary of keys to values and values to keys (thus the check for string, which you might not need). The self.field* were all dictionaries:

```
fieldenum = fielddata.mnemonics
self.fieldenums[fieldname] = fieldenum
self.fieldenumsizers[fieldname] = _wx.WrapSizer(_wx.HORIZONTAL)
fes = self.fieldenumsizers[fieldname]
self.fieldenumwindows[fieldname] = []
for fe in [x for x in fieldenum if isinstance(x, basestring)]:
    self.fieldenumwindows[fieldname].append(_wx.CheckBox(self, -1, label=fe))
    fes.Add(self.fieldenumwindows[fieldname][-1])
fes.Layout()
self.outsizer.Add(fes, 0, _wx.EXPAND)
```

If you don't expect to go over a single line, you should use a regular BoxSizer in HORIZONTAL mode, as the WrapSizer can be tricky to get working in complicated setups (i think mine was a case where i wanted going horizontally a button, then a wrapping list of checkboxes, then another checkbox, then a button, then a textctrl. In this case, because the parent sizer & the wrap sizer are both horizontal, it gets confused. Solution: wrap the WrapSizer in a vertical BoxSizer, and then include that in the horizontal BoxSizer, and that appears to work).